# Gujarati text in Spinner in Android

Tags: android, spinner

My Android app would be in Gujarati. Now I know how to embed Gujarati fonts in app and then using it on TextView and Button. But I also want to use it on Spinners. As the strings in the Spinner comes from String resourse then how to use Gujarati fonts in this case?

Comment: Consider the following link:
http://gate2home.com/Gujarati-Keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I can give you one demo for that:**

**[1]**  Open eclipse

**[2]**  Click File > New > Other > Android > (Selece) Android Sample Project > next > Select your API level >  SELECT **SoftKeyboard DEMO** > 
Give name  AND SAMPLE PROJECT WILL BE CREATED

**[3]**  In that you can find  res > xml > qwerty.xml

which contains

```
Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"
                                          ^  Here you can change your font
```

Now, you have to make your own app that overrides this SoftKeyboard.

Comment: where are you trying to lead us???

Comment: @Andro, I asked him that I was giving demo (of in-built SoftKeyboard Service).

Comment: fine. But don't think that I am the Down Voter. Its somebody else. I just thought of clearing my doubt abt your answer.

Comment: No, I have not asked to any-one that why I was down-voted, I was just informing.